# Delphi - With a Interface inside a Interface I get a Memory leak but don't know why

Tags: delphi, memory-leaks, interface, ini

My goal is, to get a Settings interface, that hold Information of my App Settings. That could be Informations, that are only relevant when the App is runing and Informations that should be permanent. For that I thought it would be a good idea to Create a app Interface and a Persistent Settings interface inside that app Settings Interface, so I can switch between let's say Ini File, DB, Crypted File, whatever.... afterwards.
Code Works, I think. But on closing FastMM leaves me with a Memory Leak in TiniFile and I do not know why. Here is the Interface unit with classes.

```
unit UAPPSettings;

interface

uses
  IniFiles;

type
  IPersistentSettings = Interface
    ['{11542859-DEA3-4DBB-9A88-2068E407552C}']
    function ReadString(Section, Name, Default: String): string;
    procedure WriteString(Section, Name, Default: String);
    function ReadPassword: string;
    procedure WritePassword(Password: String);
  end;

type
  IAppSettings = Interface
    ['{559B8219-7D81-44CA-87A0-6D261B4A87E7}']
    function GetPersistentSettings: IPersistentSettings;
    property PersistentSettings: IPersistentSettings read GetPersistentSettings;
  End;

type
  TAppSettings = class(TInterfacedObject, IAppSettings)
  strict private
    FPersistentSettings: IPersistentSettings;
    function GetPersistentSettings: IPersistentSettings;
    procedure SetPersistentSettings(const Value: IPersistentSettings);
    property PersistentSettings: IPersistentSettings read GetPersistentSettings write SetPersistentSettings;
    function _AddRef: Integer; stdcall;
    function _Release: Integer; stdcall;
  public
    constructor create(aPersistentSettings: IPersistentSettings);
  end;

type
  TIniSettings = class(TInterfacedObject, IPersistentSettings)
  strict private
    FIniFile: TIniFile;
    FfilePath: String;
    function _AddRef: Integer; stdcall;
    function _Release: Integer; stdcall;
    function ReadString(Section, Name, Default: String): string;
    procedure WriteString(Section, Name, Default: String);
    function ReadPassword: string;
    procedure WritePassword(Password: string);
  public
    constructor create(FilePath: String);

  end;

  var
  APPSettings: IAppSettings;

implementation

uses
  FMX.Types;



  { TIniSettings }

constructor TIniSettings.create(FilePath: String);
begin
  FfilePath := FilePath;
end;

function TIniSettings.ReadPassword: string;
begin
  Result := ReadString('App', 'Passwort', '');
end;

function TIniSettings.ReadString(Section, Name, Default: String): string;
begin
  If FIniFile.ValueExists(Section, Name) = false then
    WriteString(Section, Name, Default);
  Result := FIniFile.ReadString(Section, Name, Default);
end;

procedure TIniSettings.WritePassword(Password: string);
begin
  WriteString('App', 'Passwort', Password);
end;

procedure TIniSettings.WriteString(Section, Name, Default: String);
begin
  FIniFile.WriteString(Section, Name, Default);
end;

function TIniSettings._AddRef: Integer;
begin
  log.d('IniSettings _AddRef');
  FIniFile := TIniFile.create(FfilePath);
  Result := inherited _AddRef;
end;

function TIniSettings._Release: Integer;
begin
  log.d('IniSettings _Release');
  Result := inherited _Release;
  FIniFile.Free;
  FIniFile := nil;
end;

{ TAppSettings }

constructor TAppSettings.create(aPersistentSettings: IPersistentSettings);
begin
  FPersistentSettings := aPersistentSettings;
end;

function TAppSettings.GetPersistentSettings: IPersistentSettings;
begin
  Result := FPersistentSettings;
end;

procedure TAppSettings.SetPersistentSettings(const Value: IPersistentSettings);
begin
  FPersistentSettings := Value;
end;

function TAppSettings._AddRef: Integer;
begin
  log.d('AppSettings _AddRef');
  Result := inherited _AddRef;
end;

function TAppSettings._Release: Integer;
begin
  log.d('AppSettings _Release');
  Result := inherited _Release;
  FPersistentSettings := nil;
end;

end.
```

Here is how I create the Object:

```
APPSettings := TAppSettings.create(TIniSettings.create(System.IOUtils.TPath.GetDocumentsPath + System.SysUtils.PathDelim + 'config.ini'));
```

Any suggestions for better coding as well are really appreciated

Comment: Why don't you put the memory handling of the ``TIniFile`` in the classes ``constructor`` and ``destructor``?

Comment: Think about what happens in `TIniSettings._AddRef` when the reference count goes to 2. And then do what @DelphiCoder said.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem in your code is that you are using `_AddRef` and `_Release` methods for purposes other than memory management of instance upon which those two methods are called.

Following code is cause of the problem:

```
function TIniSettings._AddRef: Integer;
begin
  log.d('IniSettings _AddRef');
  FIniFile := TIniFile.create(FfilePath);
  Result := inherited _AddRef;
end;

function TIniSettings._Release: Integer;
begin
  log.d('IniSettings _Release');
  Result := inherited _Release;
  FIniFile.Free;
  FIniFile := nil;
end;
```

You are constructing `FIniFile` instance in `_AddRef` method and this is the wrong place to do that, and `_Release` is wrong place to free `FIniFile`.

`_AddRef` and `_Release` methods can be called multiple times during instance lifetime and each call to `_AddRef` would result with construction of new `TIniFile` instance.

For proper memory management those two methods will be called equal number of times,  but it is possible that `_AddRef` will be called multiple times in a row, then multiple `_Release` calls will follow at some time in the future depending on the code.

In other words, following sequence(s) are also possible:

```
_AddRef
_AddRef
_Release
_Release
```

or

```
_AddRef
_AddRef
_Release
_AddRef
_Release
_Release
```

When you call `APPSettings := TAppSettings.create(TIniSettings.create(...` first _`AddRef` will be called when passing instance as `aPersistentSettings` parameter because it is not declared as const. Then next `_AddRef` will be called when assigning `aPersistentSettings` to `FPersistentSettings` and this second call will create leak of `TIniFile` instance.

At the end of constructor call there will be matching `_Release` call for `aPersistentSettings` parameter `_AddRef` call. This will also release ini file and `FIniFile` will be `nil` and unusable until you trigger reference counting on `FPersistentSettings` instance again.

---

You would want to create `FIniFile` either in `TIniSettings` constructor and destroy it in its destructor, or introduce additional methods (`Open/Close`) to the `TIniSettings` that will serve that purpose if you don't want to have that ini file created all the time and you would call them around any reading or writing operations.

And when you remove code related to ini file from `_AddRef` and `_Release`, you no longer need to implement them in your classes as default implementation will do the job.

---

There is additional way to fix the code by creating `TIniFile` only if it is not assigned in `_AddRef`, but reference counting methods are still wrong place to do such things as you would have to ensure that you don't accidentally trigger additional reference counting in the wrong place which might leave you with nil `FIniFile` variable while you may still need it.

```
function TIniSettings._AddRef: Integer;
begin
  log.d('IniSettings _AddRef');
  if not Assigned(FIniFile) then
    FIniFile := TIniFile.create(FfilePath);
  Result := inherited _AddRef;
end;
```

Comment: Thank you for that detailed Answer. I was not aware of the difference between the reference counting and the memory management. Thank you!

Comment: Reference counting is memory management technique. When reference count drops to zero the instance is released. And the actual reference counting happens in `_AddRef` and `_Release` methods which compiler inserts at appropriate places. If you inspect implemenation in `TInterfacedObject` you can see how it works. Another variant with disabled memory management can be seen in `TNoRefCountObject` or `TComponent`. If the reference counting is disabled then instances of such class need to be manually released.